# Prompting users to answer something in the middle of the game in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there a way to ask the users a question in the middle of gaming or after the users won/lost the game? The code below is a code i wrote to ask for the players for consent and I changed it a bit. I'm not sure how should I change it though, plus I wanted to send the response as a email to myself.

```
--Asking user a question, response is printed out in the Simulator Output and emailed to me
local alert = native.showAlert( "Question", "Are the controls difficult to master?", { "Yes", "No" }, gameFun )
local function gameFun( event )
    print( "User's decision is ".. event.index .. "    User answered the question " .. event.action )

    local action = event.action
    if "clicked" == event.action then
        if 2 == event.index then

        end
    elseif "cancelled" == event.action then
        -- our cancelAlert timer function dismissed the alert so do nothing
    end
end
```

Ok, i have now changed my codes a bit, i think i could use an alert box only once so i've done this:

```
function gameFun()
    balloonText.isVisible = false
    balloonTextt.isVisible = false
    balloonTexttt.isVisible = false
    questionText.isVisible = false
    askUser = display.newText(
        'Is the cannon hard to use? Rate it at a scale of 1-5(5 the best)', 
        display.contentCenterX, 
        display.contentWidth / 4, 
        native.systemFont, 20 ) 
    askUser:setFillColor(135, 75, 44)
    yesBtn = display.newImage("Yes.png",120,290)
    noBtn = display.newImage("No.png",190,290)
end

function gameFunListener(action)
    if (action=='add') then
        yesBtn:addEventListener ('tap', sendMail())
        noBtn:addEventListener ('tap', sendMail())
    else
        yesBtn:removeEventListener ('tap', sendMail())
        noBtn:removeEventListener ('tap', sendMail())
    end
end
```

I've created a new function which will ask users a question, if the users press yes or no, they will go to the email option where they could send a email and tell me. But for some reason the buttons don't work and it jumps to write a email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some place in your game (like an enterFrame event handler, or other event handler) your game determines that user has won or lost. This is where you call your askQuestion() (or survey) function. There are many ways to do this, but basically

- if you are using storyboard, you would make the question a new scene that you transition to (`currentScene.gotoScene("newscene")`);
- otherwise (no storyboard) you could make some of the visible display objects invisible, instantiate some question widgets (text for question, buttons for answers, etc) and make those visible

When last question answered, you restore the view to what it was before questions (or show a "game over" page etc). Corona, as other GUI, is based on events that result from user action (press button, enter text, move an object to collide with another, etc), and system events (enterFrame, orientation, suspend/resume, etc), so the trigger that causes the display of your questions is in one of those event handlers.

For example:

```
function gameFun()
    balloonText.isVisible = false
    ...
    askUser = display.newText(
        'Is the cannon hard to use? Rate it at a scale of 1-5(5 the best)', 
        display.contentCenterX, 
        display.contentWidth / 4, 
        native.systemFont, 20 ) 
    askUser:setFillColor(135, 75, 44)
    yesBtn = display.newImage("Yes.png",120,290)
    noBtn = display.newImage("No.png",190,290)
    yesBtn:addEventListener ('tap', processAnswer)
    noBtn:addEventListener ('tap', processAnswer)
end

function processAnswer(event)
    if event.target == noBtn then 
        ...
    else
        ...
    end
    sendMail()
    askUser.isVisible = false
    yesBtn.isVisible = false
    ...
    yesBtn:removeEventListener ('tap', processAnswer)
    noBtn:removeEventListener ('tap', processAnswer)
end
```

Beware than when you register a listener, you must not call the function that you are registering (no `()` after the function name)! Also, if you create your question display objects at the beginning and then just toggle their visibility on in gameFun and off in processAnswer, then you don't need to worry about removeEventListener: they will respond to tap only while visible.

Comment: i'm not using storyboard though, i know storyboard is convenient but is there another way instead of using storyboard?

Comment: @user3305142 This is in my answer, but perhaps not clear, I edited, comment if still not clear.

Comment: Is it like the one i posted an hour ago?